# Swagger 5.0 - IDocumentFilter (SwaggerDocument to OpenApiDocument) custom "Definitions"

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle, asp.net-core-3.1

We are in process of migrating the application from .NET Core 2.1 to 3.1 for which we need to upgrade **swagger from 4.X to 5.X** as well. With swagger 4.x we were able to remove certain properties that were marked with a specific attribute with something like the following:

```
public class SwaggerIgnoreFilter : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        var allTypes = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(i => i.GetTypes()).ToList();

        foreach (var definition in swaggerDoc?.Definitions)
        {
            var type = allTypes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == definition.Key);
            if (type != null)
            {
                var properties = type.GetProperties();
                foreach (var prop in properties.ToList())
                {
                    var ignoreAttribute = prop.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(SwaggerIgnoreAttribute), false);

                    if (ignoreAttribute != null)
                    {
                        definition.Value.Properties.Remove(prop.Name);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that with swagger 5.0, the IDocumentFilter has changed and we have OpenApiDocument in place of SwaggerDocument which has taken away **Definitions** property and we are unable to figure out how to hide certain properties from the swagger pages. Any help/suggestion/link would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Now you can use `swaggerDoc.Components.Schemas`

```
public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
{
    var allTypes = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(i => i.GetTypes()).ToList();

    foreach (var definition in swaggerDoc.Components.Schemas)
    {
        var type = allTypes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == definition.Key);
        if (type != null)
        {
            var properties = type.GetProperties();
            foreach (var prop in properties.ToList())
            {
                var ignoreAttribute = prop.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(SwaggerIgnoreAttribute), false);

                if (ignoreAttribute != null)
                {
                    definition.Value.Properties.Remove(prop.Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick turn-around time.

Comment: Glad to have been of help